# Critical Update Not Found in Different Sandbox

Tags: case, critical-update

We faced a case assignment rule email sending issue in the past on our one sandbox and contacted with support. They fixed that using a critical update.

**Update Name:** Stop Automated Field Updates from Suppressing Email Notifications

**Update Summary:** This update stops processes, workflow rules, and Apex triggers from suppressing email notifications.

Now we are facing same issue in another sandbox but we unable to find the critical update in another sandbox. How can we find that critical update? Is there a way around so that I can activate that critical update in our another sandbox?

https://xxxxx.lightning.force.com/lightning/setup/CriticalUpdates/home

[image]

Comment: Maybe it is already active. Can you check if it is present in other tabs?

Comment: Not present in other tabs, and if its activated then case assignment rule should send the email as it assigns to target user but no email sent to the case owner.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I contacted support in regard of this issue.

If someone is facing the same issue then you should consider following.

- For now the critical update "**stop automated field updates from suppressing email notifications**" is not available in sandbox due to the release.
- Link: https://trailblazer.salesforce.com/issues_view?title=winter-21-stop-automated-field-updates-from-suppressing-email-notifications-critical-update-changes&Id=a1p4V0000003wVR
- Please click on "This issue affects me" to add yourself to the
  Reported By count. Status of the KI is "Scheduled" to be in Winter
  '21 Patch 8.0.

Answer (score 0):

You probably cannot find the critical update because it is already enabled in the org as per [release notes](https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/spring20/release-notes/rn_forcecom_flow_pbuilder_cruc_process_emails.htm) :

> Stop Automated Field Updates from Suppressing Email Notifications was a critical update in Summer ’17 and is enforced in Spring ’20, on March 1, 2020. For various operations, such as assigning a task to someone, you can choose to notify the affected user by email. This update stops processes, workflow rules, and Apex triggers from suppressing these email notifications. This change applies to Lightning Experience and Salesforce Classic.

But currently there are active known issues related to this critical update, refer to links below to see if any of these affect you

[Missing or duplicate emails when "Stop Automated Field Updates from Suppressing Email Notifications" is enabled](https://trailblazer.salesforce.com/issues_view?title=missing-or-duplicate-emails-when-stop-automated-field-updates-from-suppressing-email-notifications-is-enabled&Id=a1p3A000000EX9r)

["Stop Automated Field Updates from Suppressing Email Notifications" sending duplicate assignment email for Opportunity record](https://trailblazer.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p3A0000018As9QAE&title=stop-automated-field-updates-from-suppressing-email-notifications-sending-duplicate-assignment-email-for-opportunity-record)

Comment: If it is already enabled then it should work fine as I have scenario where case will be assigned to target user using case assignment rule and email template is also chosen from the settings of case assignment rule settings. Same settings on another sandbox are working fine but not on another sandbox, deployment was done using change set from the working sanbox to new sandbox.

Comment: Is email deliverability enabled in this new sandbox? Also, if not already done, I suggest to log a case with SF support to report this. You may be experiencing another issue related to this critical update

Comment: Yes, email Deliverability Access level is All Email and I am trying to contact with support to fix this issue. I am wondering if these changes go to production then may be that has the same issue. Let's see.

Comment: @KamranJabbar did you get any update from SF support for this ?

Comment: Yes, they said
For now the critical update "stop automated field updates from suppressing email notifications" is not available in sandbox due to the release.
Link: https://trailblazer.salesforce.com/issues_view?title=winter-21-stop-automated-field-updates-from-suppressing-email-notifications-critical-update-changes&Id=a1p4V0000003wVR
Please click on "This issue affects me" to add yourself to the Reported By count.
Status of the KI is "Scheduled" to be in Winter '21 Patch 8.0.
But it was available on our production so I fixed it on production by activating that.

Comment: @KamranJabbar I guess you can post this an answer, so that its more visible for others having same issue